# Resizable contenteditable with external handles

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, contenteditable, jquery-ui-resizable

I have an editable text block, which I wish to be resizable. If I place handles inside it, all works perfect except that element is editable and user can delete handles while editing it:

```
<div id="drag-area">
    <div id="text-block" class="lighter-heading hidden text-block">
        <div class="editable-text" contenteditable>
            Editable block
           <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw nw handle"></div>
           <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne ne handle"></div>
           <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw sw handle"></div>
           <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se se handle"></div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Ve4U/154/

If I try to place handles in the parent div, element doesn't become resizable at all:

```
<div id="drag-area">
    <div id="text-block" class="lighter-heading hidden text-block">
        <div class="editable-text" contenteditable>
            Editable block
        </div>  
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw nw handle"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne ne handle"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw sw handle"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se se handle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Ve4U/155/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

try to change:

```
   .editable-text {
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width:400px;
    min-height: 18px;
    position: absolute;    
}
```

check it: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ve4U/157/

Comment: you can use textbox for prevent editable. Like this: <input id="Text1" readonly="true" type="text" />